# EMPTY CDATA in XML

Tags: xml, cdata

```
<body><![CDATA[]]></body>
```

or

```
<body></body>
```

Is there a difference or downside to each? Do I need to do anything while parsing the XML? What do you prefer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as the XML parser is concerned there is NO difference.  If you wish to force CDATA creation during XSLT output there is an option (cdata-section-elements) that can be used to cause certain elements to output CDATA.